# How to edit specific field value,only if another field value is changed?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource, datarowview

I have `WinForm aplication,.Net framework 4.5` with `vs2012 and Sqlserver 2008 R2`.

In my form i use `"BindingSource_CurrentItemChanged"` to add new value if `row.IsNew` (user insert a new row)

```
 DataRowView row = (DataRowView) this.BindingSource.Current;
 //if row is null then exit form method.
 if(row==null)
    return;
 if(row.IsNew)
    {
      row["CreatedUserID"] = this.UserID;
      row["ModifiedUserID"] = this.UserID;
    }
```

This worked successfully.

Then i want to write a method that when user edit a desire field value, my code put "UserID" to ModifiedUserID automatically (some thing like this):

```
  ... row["ModifiedUserID"] = this.UserID;
```

I used below code in `BindongSource_ListChanged` but get error:

```
if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
        {
            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)this.ApplicationFilesBindingSource.Current;
            if (row == null)
                return;
            row["ModifiedUserID"] = this.ID;
        }
```

Error:
     DataTable Internal Index is corrupted: '5'.

after this if write a code in `BindingSource_CurrentItemChanged`

```
  if (row.Row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
            row["ModifiedUserID"] = User.User.Current.ID;
```

this code also raise a same exception too:

Error:
     DataTable Internal Index is corrupted: '5'.

Where do i put this code for change `"ModifiedUserID"` to this.UserID?
 in which event of `BindingSource` or `DataGridView` ?

Comment: Do you have a Sort expression on your BindingSource by any chance ?

Comment: May be. because user may sort records by click specific DataGridView Header.